# label positioning in gnuplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I'd like to have the x and y labels at the end of the axis, next to the arrows:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.7, 
      every node/.style={transform shape} ]

    \begin{axis}[
      xmin = -5, xmax = 5, ymin = -5, ymax = 5,  % osy
      axis equal image,
      axis x line = middle,
      axis y line = middle,
      xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
      ]

      \addplot[color=red, samples=100, smooth, ultra thick, unbounded coords=jump, no markers, 
               domain = -4:4] gnuplot{x*x*x-x};

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to TeX.SX! Just adding a line `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` and everything works fine:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.7, 
      every node/.style={transform shape} ]

    \begin{axis}[
      xmin = -5, xmax = 5, ymin = -5, ymax = 5,  % osy
      axis equal image,
      axis x line = middle,
      axis y line = middle,
      xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
      ]

      \addplot[color=red, samples=100, smooth, ultra thick, unbounded coords=jump, no markers, 
               domain = -4:4] gnuplot{x*x*x-x};

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]